# Highlight active div link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create kind of a simple content box slider as follows:

```
$('.boxes:not(:first)').hide();
    $(".links a:first").addClass("selected"); 
    $(".links a").click(function() {
        var activeLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
        $(".links a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $(activeLink).fadeIn();
});
```

On click an element show the linked div and highlight the clicked link: This works fine. What I want to achieve is show next div as you click on the active div and **highlight the active div link**

I am trying to achieve that with:

```
$('.boxes').click(function(){
    var $activeBox = $(this);
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $activeBox.next().show();
});
```

I skip to the next box(div) on click div but how can I highlight active div link?
Exp: if box1 is being displayed then highlight link1 or box2 is being displayed then highlight link2 and so on..

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/13mg30Lf/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

```
$('.boxes').click(function(){
 var $activeBox = $(this);
 $('.boxes').hide();
 $activeBox.next().show();
 var $activelink = $(".selected");
 $activelink.removeClass("selected");
 $activelink.next().addClass("selected");
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13mg30Lf/2/

Answer (score 0):

A more **short and reusable** code:

```
 $('.boxes').click(function(){
        var $activeBox = $(this);
        $(".links a[href=#"+$activeBox.next().attr('id')+"]").click();

    });
```